# Installation failure while trying to install Black Magic Design's Desktop Video 9.7.7

Tags: windows-server-2008

When attempting to install Black Magic Design's Desktop Video application/driver package (version 9.7.7) on Windows 2008 Server R2 Service Pack 1, the installer fails when it reaches the step "Installing services". It then proceeds to roll back the install and quit the installer. Has anyone been successful in resolving this?

Comment: What did Blackmagic tell you when you contacted them?

Comment: What does the Event Viewer say?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Black Magic was less than helpful. I was able to determine the solution (which I posted below for others who run into the same issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging, it appears the problem is caused by the Desktop Video Helper Service not being able to start:

> Info 1920.Service 'Desktop Video Helper Service' (dvhlp) failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.

Attempting to start the service manually from the MMC Service control panel returns the following error message:

> Error 14001: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is in correct. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

While the event log contains the error:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Blackmagic Design\Blackmagic Desktop Video\DesktopVideoHelper.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

The solution was to install the x86 Visual C++ 2008 SP1 redistributable runtime component below, provided by Microsoft:

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

Although the server is running the 64-bit version of Windows 2008 Server R2 SP1, the x86/32-bit version of the runtime was required.